# How to change the host from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 in a webpack + Node project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, networking, webpack

I have a project using webpack and Node.

When I run this project in local, it's normal:

> listening at localhost:1234

and I can see it with address 127.0.0.1:1234 in the browser.

But when I run this project in my ECS（Linux), it is still running at 127.0.0.1:1234, but I need it to be listening at 0.0.0.1:1234, so I can see it with address <Public network IP>:1234.

I have already added `host:'0.0.0.0'` in `project/cfg/base.js`, but it does not work, it still listens at 127.0.0.1:1234.

Which config do I have to change or how can I see the project with <Public network IP>:1234?

Comment: Are you using webpack-dev-server?

Comment: Just a sidenote: Most bigger production web applications do not listen on any interface other than 127.0.0.1, instead they use a reverse proxy on the same machine (safety, load-balancing, TLS are just some advantages).

Comment: i am not vary familiar to the working principle of webpack.In my computer,i use the code `node server.js` in the root directory to start my project, `server.js` has require the `webpack.config` and `webpack-dev-server`, and `webpack.config` require the files in `./cfg/base.js&defaults.js&dev.js&dist.js&test,js`,so i think there is some config i can do to change the listening port, but i cannot find the right way,and i am so sorry that i cannot upload the image bacause of the terrible network state.